# Como guardar Imagen de Perfil del boton de Google o Facebook en firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase

mi pregunta es: mediante FirebaseAuth obtengo los datos del usuario y esos datos lo paso a Firebase Database incluyendo la URL de la imagen de perfil ==> mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();

a Firebase database la paso mediante mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString(); de lo cual obtengo la Url de la imagen

lo que quiero es agarrar esa URL de imagen de perfil y guardarla en firebase Storage

y de mi storage adquirir la nueva URL de la imagen y mostrar al usuario la imagen

en otras palabras quiero obtener la imagen y guardarla en mi storage

gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Para tu caso mi recomendación seria usar [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) que te permiten tener funciones de Node.js alojadas en la misma infraestructura serverless de Firebase.
Las Functions estan diseñadas para reaccionar a eventos de servicios Firebase, como por ejemplo "se creó un nuevo registro en la BD" o "se registro un usuario nuevo". de esa forma puedes captar las URLs de las fotos y dentro de la misma funcion descargar la imagen para guardarla en storage.